# C# - I need to add code! Guess the number

Tags: c#

I have written a guess the number game between 1-100.
This is my code..

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int randno = Newnum(1, 101);
            int count = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Guess a number between 1 and 100, or press 0 to quit: ");
                int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (input == 0)
                    return;
                else if (input < randno)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unlucky, that number is too low - have another go!");
                    ++count;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (input > randno)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unlucky, that number is too high - have another go!");
                    ++count;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Well done - you guessed it! The number was {0}.", randno);
                    Console.WriteLine("It took you {0} {1}.\n", count, count == 1 ? "attempt" : "attempts to guess it right");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    static int Newnum(int min, int max)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next(min, max);
    }
}
```

How can I edit it so that if a user gets close to the number, say within 5 numbers, they are greeted with a message saying they're close?

Comment: Are you really asking "How can I tell if number X is within 5 of number Y"? If so, I suggest you reduce your question to that, showing what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Math.Abs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk4666yx(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int diff = Math.Abs(input - randno);
if(diff <= 5)
{
    // say him that he's close
}
```